# How to design a database table in a context where the columns can potentially change with each new row

Tags: database, sqlite

Lets consider the following task: For a NLP task I am collecting news title in a database. I need to use this data for word frequency analysis, so I tokenize the title and store the words in the following way:

titles table:

```
titleID    word1    word2    word3    ....   
1          0        0        1   
2          1        1        0   
3          0        0        0   
...
```

Every column is a different word, and i mark it 0 or 1 according to whether or not it is present in the title.

The issue is of course that each time i add a new title, there might be a word that is new and therefore I would need to add a new column for this word.

In SQL world that means a potential migration at each insert of a new row, which is not tenable. I could use nosql but I would still like that table to have relations with other tables in my database.

What would be the alternatives for my case? What is the common way to store NLP data in a database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not so sure about the NLP aspect, and it obviously depends heavily on the usage scenario, but the relational solution to this is that you have a many-to-many relationship between "titles" and "words".

More formally:

```
A title has one or more words.
A word appears in zero or more titles. A word may appear more than once in a title, with an index signifying it's position in each case.
```

The schema is then:

```
Words
-----
Word_id (PK)
Word

Titles
------
Title_id (PK)
TItle

Word-Title
------------
Word_id. (PK, FK)
Title_id (PK, FK)
Index.   (PK)
```

This means that when you encounter new words in a title, you insert a new row into the "words" table, rather than appending a column.